# How to open a .download file to preview it

Tags: file

One friend of mine has some files with the extension .download
as google chrome downloaded them they havent finished yet.

Is there any possible way to preview the content of them???

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Possibly, if you know what file extension they should have been ..

Comment: @Stewart nope he doesnt have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'.download' is a partially downloaded file.I don't think you can preview the content.

check [this](http://filext.com/file-extension/DOWNLOAD) for more information.